# 81 Level Inverter Problem when using a Motor as a Load (Simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink

i made a VFD based on (See reference 1).
The problem is that, when connecting a Motor (Asyncrhonous Machine SI) as the load... the Noise just goes crazy.
First, using an RLC Series Load (Default) i have this output (measurement using a Three-Phase Measurement Block)
[image: Text]
Some voltage noise, but it works as expected, next using an squirrel Cage (default 575 settings) with an constant input of 1 Tm, i get:
[image: Text]
Which is not expected at all. The results are the same in discrete or continuous.... and so on
General view of the system:
[image: Text]
Detailed view of Phase A:
[image: Text]
Reference 1:
J. Rahila, M. Santhi and A. Kannabhiran, "A new 81 level inverter with reduced number of switches," IEEE-International Conference On Advances In Engineering, Science And Management (ICAESM -2012), Nagapattinam, India, 2012, pp. 485-489.